# Group subarrays based on column value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, grouping, array-merge

I have an array:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c',2], ['d',2]]
```

How can I group the subarrays based on the second column value like this:

```
[[['a', 1], ['b', 1]], [['c',2], ['d',2]]]
```

I have an idea to solve this with a foreach, but it may have a way with the built-in functions?

Sketch with foreach:

```
$in = [['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c',2], ['d',2]];
$out = [];

foreach($in as $i) {
    $out[$i[1]][] = $i;
}
```

Comment: Can you alter the format of the input array?

Comment: Do you want to always split it in half or in sets of two?

Comment: [Here's the list of PHP built-in array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

Comment: @Kasapo No. It can be split many parts.

Comment: @Lübnah About the list of built-in functions, I know. But in this task, I do not know how to use them. And is it possible at all. Can you rephrase your first question? Unfortunately, I do not understand.

Comment: If the 2nd element in the inner arrays always refer to the index of the "column" it belongs to, then your solution is fine. I don't really think there's anything built in for this.

Comment: @Ticksy Sorry, what I meant was, are you in control of the way that data is originally formatted? E.g., do you have control of the data source?

Comment: This is an array grouping problem, your approach is correct assuming you are not building `$in` (if you are, just build it grouped). See more @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189626/php-how-to-group-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-particular-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You more or less have what I would have arrived at for a solution.

As long as the data that you wish to use as an index will always be in the same position in the array, you will be able to hardcode the index as you have done in the collector array.

If not, I would think about moving to an associative array and assigning a name to the value that you want to use as an index when creating the array.

```
[['a', 'index'=>1] [etc...]]

$out[$i[index]][] = $i;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to preserve the value that you use as an index, incidentally?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native php function that will group on the column value of an indexed array of indexed arrays.  If you were talking about associative arrays, the `array_merge_recursive()` might be of interest.

([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WCqgS))

Basic loop syntax: (more concise, usually faster)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[$row[1]][] = $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

Functional syntax: (more declarative, no new global variable declared)

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function ($carry, $row) {
            $carry[$row[1]][] = $row;
            return $carry;
        }
    )
);
```

If you wish to re-index the result (remove the group keys), then call `array_values()` on the result.

Answer (score -1):

The only PHP built-in that's specific to multi-dimensional arrays seems to be [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), which won't be of much help unless there are assumptions we can make about the data contained within the input array.

In the case of a small dataset, your brute-force example seems fine to me.