# How to group rows of data into subarrays based on another column?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, merging-data

What is the best way to group data in my multi-dimensional array by one column and crate a subarray of from another column in each group?

```
$array = [
    ['idAnswer' => 209, 'idQuestion' => 141],
    ['idAnswer' => 1668, 'idQuestion' => 141],
    ['idAnswer' => 211, 'idQuestion' => 142]
];
```

I need to get: `[['209', '1668'], ['211']]`.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Iterate over array, group values as you need.

Comment: You could either use array_map or array_column

Comment: look it, pls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152920/php-multidimensional-array-get-values

Comment: I'll see if I can find a better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66937131/2943403