# How to sum values via the same key and group by other key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I'd like to sum products by the same ref number, but I have 3rd parameter like dimension e.g. (..., 24, 26mm,...) and I can't sum this values **only** when they have the same dimension. I tried this: [Group a multidimensional array by a particular value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189626/group-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-particular-value) but how to sum values?
My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 790180X
            [2] => 26mm
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 762182Z
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 072182X
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 660122Y
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 790180X
            [2] => 24mm
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 225160Y
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 244160Y
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 225160Y
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 954120Y
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 072182X
        )
)
```

I'd like to something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 790180X
        [2] => 26mm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 790180X
        [2] => 24mm
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 762182Z
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 072182X
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 660122Y
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 225160Y
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 244160Y
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 954120Y
        )
)
```

The array in short version:

```
Array               =>  TO =>       Array
(                                   (
    [0] => 2:790180X:26mm           [0] => 2:790180X:26mm
    [1] => 4:762182Z                [1] => 2:790180X:24mm
    [2] => 2:072182X                [2] => 4:762182Z
    [3] => 4:660122Y                [3] => 5:072182X
    [4] => 2:790180X:24mm           [4] => 4:660122Y
    [5] => 1:225160Y                [5] => 2:225160Y
    [6] => 1:244160Y                [6] => 1:244160Y
    [7] => 1:225160Y                [7] => 8:954120Y
    [8] => 8:954120Y                )
    [9] => 3:072182X
)
```

Comment: I tried @Gerard Banasig answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189626/group-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-particular-value but not this i expect.

Comment: @Pitchinnate your code worked too.

Comment: Yeah Marc's is more concise so I figured I would remove mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sum into a new array, using the various "grouping" fields as keys in the new array:

```
$sums = array();
foreach ($yourarray as $element) {
    $sums[$element['dimension1']][$element['dimension2']]++;
}
```

For every dimension you need to 'group' by, you add a key to the $sums array.

Comment: I'm little bit closer - I think, but how to sum first value (like quantity).

Comment: `... += $element['quantity'];`