# wordpress get category name of custom post type in wordpress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the category name of custom post type in query posts loop.

here is my code:

```
query_posts(array('post_type'=>'portfolio','posts_per_page'=>4, 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'DESC' ));

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

<li>
    <div class="foli_img"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"> <span class="next"> </span> </a> <?php the_post_thumbnail();?> </div>
    <h3 class="style"><?php the_title();?></h3>
    <?php the_content();?>
    <h4><a  href="#">I want the category name here</a></h4>
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Try this inside a loop: `<?php echo get_cat_name(get_the_ID()) ?>`

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola its still not working though i am getting the id in the loop but still not getting the category name

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502811/display-current-post-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php

    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post();?>
        <li>
            <div class="foli_img">
               <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"> 
                   <span class="next"> </span> 
               </a> 
               <?php the_post_thumbnail();?> 
            </div>
            <h3 class="style"><?php the_title();?></h3>
            <?php the_content();?>
            <h4><a  href="#">
            <?php 
               $category = get_the_category( $post->ID );
               echo $category[0]->cat_name;?></a></h4>
        </li>
    <?php 
    endwhile;?>
```

or

Try get through terms :

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'Enter_your_taxonomy_here' );
if ($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms)) :
    $tslugs_arr = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $tslugs_arr[] = $term->slug;
    }
    $terms_slug_str = join( " ", $tslugs_arr);
endif;
echo $terms_slug_str;
```

Comment: its still not working i tried to print the code like this and i am getting a blank array
 $category = get_the_category( $post->ID ); print_r($category);

Comment: @NitinJohnson are you able to get the post id by `$post->ID` and also do yopu have multiple category selected for the posts?

Comment: Yes i am getting the post id. No i have only one category assigned to the custom post type

Comment: @NitinJohnson Can you post the $category out put to the question?

Comment: i am getting a blank array like this when i try to print the category      Array ( )

Comment: @NitinJohnson Have you added the taxonomy at the time time registering the custom post type. Can you share the code of register custom post type?

Comment: I have used a plugin called Custom Post Type UI for creating the custom post type and category for custom post type

Comment: @NitinJohnson i have added another solution by using terms ,see if it works?

Comment: Code using terms worked like a charm. Good solution.