# PHP arrays combine values of the right key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question about arrays in PHP:

I have many zip files having many data inside and using preg_grep I could get the results below:

(These data are returned from multiple text files in the zip file)

```
    => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data.zip
                [Age] => 45
            )
    => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data.zip
                [Name] => John
            )
    => Array
            (
                [ZipName] => data2.zip
            )
    => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data1.zip
                [Age] => 25 
            )
     => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data2.zip
                [Age] => 27
            )
     => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data1.zip
                [Name] => Abram
            )
     => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data1.zip
            )
     => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data2.zip
                [City] => London 
            )          
    => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data2.zip
                [Name] => Inna 
            )         
    => Array
            (
                [ZipName] =>  data1.zip
                [City] => London 
            )
```

So how I can combine/merge all of these arrays using the ZipName Value !

Like in SQL it easy :

> SELECT * FROM * WHERE ZipName= 'x';

```
0 => Array
        (
            [ZipName] =>  data.zip
            [Age] => 45
            [Name] => John
            [City] => Leicester 
        )

1 => Array
        (
            [ZipName] =>  data1.zip
            [Age] => 25
            [Name] => Abram
            [City] => London 
        )

2 => Array
        (
            [ZipName] =>  data2.zip
            [Age] => 27
            [Name] => Inna
            [City] => London
        )
```

Comment: is input array multi dimensional array or different - 2 array ??

Comment: @ForgeWebDesign no differenet 0 1 2 3 etc .. the arrays follows the total count of text files which mean each new text file a new array

Comment: then you can use array_merge() function

Comment: Does your actual data have different values for `ZipName`? Might be helpful to include that in your question.

Comment: Yes different zipname

Comment: @kadi-dz - can you please update your question with more realistic data so we understand what you want?

Comment: Effectively, you want to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62442134/2943403 but just remove the `unset()` call because you want to keep the zipname in the subarrays.  like this:  https://3v4l.org/tjtqe

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you so much that helped lot, I have another question what If I'm getting the ages with a function and names with another one and in return I have two huge arrays list, I could combine it using this ?! with considering that sometimes I get more than one name in the text file of that zip file which returns me many results

Comment: I realize that you are new to this place, but I must tell you: You are going to irritate volunteers if you keep extending/changing your requirements.  You must only ask one question per page and your requirements must not change.  I will suggest that you accept Yoshi's answer (it is the best one on the page right now).  As for your new requirements, you should go away and try and research and try, then if you need help come back and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to *group by* the unique values at the index `['ZipName']` and then *merge* those groups *individually*. This can be done with [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-reduce.php).

Example:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$input = [
    [
        'ZipName' => 'data_1.zip',
        'Age'     => 45,
    ], [
        'ZipName' => 'data_1.zip',
        'Name'    => 'John',
    ], [
        'ZipName' => 'data_1.zip',
    ], [
        'ZipName' => 'data_1.zip',
        'City'    => 'Leicester',
    ],

    [
        'ZipName' => 'data_2.zip',
        'Age'     => 45,
    ], [
        'ZipName' => 'data_2.zip',
        'Name'    => 'John',
    ], [
        'ZipName' => 'data_2.zip',
    ], [
        'ZipName' => 'data_2.zip',
        'City'    => 'Leicester',
    ],
];

$output = array_values(array_reduce($input, static function (array $acc, array $item): array {
    $acc[$item['ZipName']] = array_merge($acc[$item['ZipName']] ?? [], $item);

    return $acc;
}, []));

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `array_merge`, `array_combine` etc.. ...is just two simple foreach loops and setting the value into a new array (`$new_arr`).

```
$new_arr = [];
foreach($arr as $inner_arr) {
    foreach($inner_arr as $key=>$value) {
        $new_arr[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I was not clear what OP wanted but I hope it's clearer now:

**Try this:**
(Basically adding values to `array[name of ZipName][{current key for the inner array}]`

```
$arr = [
    [
        'ZipName' => 'data.zip',
        'Age' => '45'
    ],
    [
        'ZipName' => 'data.zip',
        'Name' => 'John'
    ],
    [
        'ZipName' => 'data2.zip',
        'Age' => '27'
    ],
    [
        'ZipName' => 'data1.zip',
        'Name' => 'Abram'
    ],
    [
        'ZipName' => 'data1.zip'
    ],    
    [
        'ZipName' =>  'data2.zip',
        'City' => 'London' 
    ],    
    [
        'ZipName' =>  'data2.zip',
        'Name' => 'Inna' 
    ],    
    [
        'ZipName' =>  'data1.zip',
        'City' => 'London' 
    ]


];


$new_arr = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $inner_arr) {
   foreach($inner_arr as $ik => $item) {
       $new_arr[$inner_arr['ZipName']][$ik] = $item;
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [data.zip] => Array
        (
            [ZipName] => data.zip
            [Age] => 45
            [Name] => John
        )

    [data2.zip] => Array
        (
            [ZipName] => data2.zip
            [Age] => 27
            [City] => London
            [Name] => Inna
        )

    [data1.zip] => Array
        (
            [ZipName] => data1.zip
            [Name] => Abram
            [City] => London
        )

)
```

**When doing:**

```
$new_arr = array_values($new_arr);
```

the key simply gets do be a numeric index (if it matters)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ZipName] => data.zip
            [Age] => 45
            [Name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ZipName] => data2.zip
            [Age] => 27
            [City] => London
            [Name] => Inna
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ZipName] => data1.zip
            [Name] => Abram
            [City] => London
        )

)
```

Comment: I need to combine it using the ZipName value !

Comment: I've modified the answer now.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are going to combine different arrays, So please use array merge.

```
   $array0 = Array
            (
                "ZipName" =>  data.zip,
                "Age" => 45
            );
   $array1 = Array
            (
                "ZipName" =>  data.zip,
                "Name" => John
            );
   $array2 = Array
            (
                "ZipName" =>  data.zip
            );
   $array3 = Array
            (
                "ZipName" =>  data.zip,
                "City" => Leicester 
            );

  print_r(array_merge($array0, $array1, $array2, $array3));
```

Out Put:

```
Array ( [ZipName] => datazip 
        [Age] => 45 
        [Name] => John 
        [City] => Leicester )
```

Comment: Yeah I got something like but what I want is to combine it using the ZipName value !