# Issue with for loop in PHP for grouping same elements in an array as one

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, laravel-5

I get some data in an associated array, see image for data,

[image]

Here I want to group all elements with `party` value. Each array may have different party name but arrays with a similar party to be grouped and displayed in the page.

What I tried is, Here I can successfully separate `golaRate` and `rate`, but I need specific party name for `golaRate` and `rate`

```
@foreach($data as $bill_data)
        @if(!$bill_data['golaRate'])
            {{-- @foreach($bill_data['party'] as $party) --}} --> this the problem here

@foreach($data as $bill_data)
        @if(!$bill_data['rate'])
            {{-- @foreach($bill_data['party'] as $party) --}}
```

am using laravel framework.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189626/group-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-particular-value

Comment: @Thamilan that answer is only separating rate and golaRate which I already did, I just need to group by party in each of them(rate, golaRate)

Comment: Create another array with keys as party names, then push each data under each party,

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanBaji you could please post a sample snippet on it.

Comment: K i will try to make one

Comment: Check my answer, that may help you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is your requirement or not, hope this may help

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        "lotname"=>"456",
        "quantity"=>"456",
        "rate"=>"5",
        "golarate"=>null,
        "userId"=>null,
        "party"=>"fds",
        ),  
    array(
        "lotname"=>"456",
        "quantity"=>"456",
        "rate"=>"5",
        "golarate"=>null,
        "userId"=>null,
        "party"=>"fds",
        ),  
    array(
        "lotname"=>"456",
        "quantity"=>"456",
        "rate"=>"5",
        "golarate"=>null,
        "userId"=>null,
        "party"=>"bbb",
        ),  
    array(
        "lotname"=>"456",
        "quantity"=>"456",
        "rate"=>"5",
        "golarate"=>null,
        "userId"=>null,
        "party"=>"bbb",
        ),
    ); 

function groupParty($data)
{
    $grouped = [];
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $grouped[$value['party']][] = $value;
    }
    return $grouped;
}

print_r(groupParty($array));
?>
```

Comment: yes am getting as needed but I need to loop through the results, and here array has a name like `Array ( [dgdfg] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [lotName] => ssf3 [quantity] => 12 [rate] => 56 [golaRate] => [userId] => [party] => dgdfg ) ` and I cont lop them like `$array[0]` like that.

Comment: Use foreach to loop u will get each party group in each loop

Comment: Or you can use array_values(groupParty($data))

Comment: Yea I used `array_values`, but finding trouble in showing them in a table properly, extended to another question please look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053820/adjusting-the-view-of-a-html-table-while-getting-data-through-a-forloop