# How to group a multidimensional array by multiple subarray values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I checked this question and answers:

[How to group a multidimensional array by a particular subarray value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189626/how-to-group-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-particular-subarray-value)

He wanted to group results by 'level'. But how would you do it to group it by 'level' first and then by 'type'?

Comment: can you please provide some input/output format that you would want? clarification of input and output would help us to answer your question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straight forward. Loop through $items array. Get each item's level and type and if they are not set yet, initialize them with an empty array. Then just push the "cust" value into the array.

I have given the code below.

I am assuming "$items" is an array which contains the input.

```
$g = [];

foreach($items as $k => $v) {
    $l = $v["level"];
    $t = $v["type"];
    $c = $v["cust"];

    if(!isset($g[$l])) {
        $g[$l] = [];
    }
    if(!isset($g[$l][$t])) {
        $g[$l][$t] = [];
    }

    $g[$l][$t][] = [
        "cust" => $c
    ];
}

var_dump($g);
```

The output of this code would be like below:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["standard"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["cust"]=>
        string(6) "XT8900"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["cust"]=>
        string(6) "XT8944"
      }
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["premier"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["cust"]=>
        string(6) "XT8922"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["cust"]=>
        string(6) "XT8816"
      }
    }
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["standard"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["cust"]=>
        string(6) "XT7434"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[P.S.]: You can also use sort to solve this problem easily. That's another way of solving this problem.