# Group values in multi-dimensional array based on a key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multi-dimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [sname] => florida
        [cname] => orlando
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [sname] => texas
        [cname] => dallas
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        [sname] => florida
        [cname] => tampa
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        [sname] => ohio
        [cname] => columbus
        )

)
```

How would I go about trying to get all '***cname***' values associated with each '***sname***' value?

```
florida:    orlando, tampa
texas:      dallas
ohio:       columbus
```

Comment: Can you post your tried code?

Comment: Do you have to use this structure? you can use state name as key e.g `['florida' => ['orlando', 'tampa']]` and then you can get state names by using `array_keys()`

Answer (score 0):

With a slight tweak of Mike's solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2189916/4954574), the following will produce what I was hoping for:

```
$input_arr = array(
    array("sname" => "florida", "cname" => "orlando"),
    array("sname" => "texas", "cname" => "dallas"),
    array("sname" => "florida", "cname" => "tampa"),
    array("sname" => "ohio", "cname" => "columbus")
);

foreach ($input_arr as $key => &$entry) {
    $level_arr[$entry['sname']][$key] = $entry['cname'];
}

print_r($level_arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [florida] => Array
        (
            [0] => orlando
            [2] => tampa
        )

    [texas] => Array
        (
            [1] => dallas
        )

    [ohio] => Array
        (
            [3] => columbus
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to do this. The one that comes to mind is something like this:

```php
<?php

$payload = [];
$origin = [
    [
        'sname' => 'florida',
        'cname' => 'orlando'
    ],
    [
        'sname' => 'texas',
        'cname' => 'dallas'
    ],
    [
        'sname' => 'florida',
        'cname' => 'tampa'
    ],
    [
        'sname' => 'ohio',
        'cname' => 'columbus'
    ]
];


foreach ($origin as $value) {
  if (! isset($payload[$value['sname']])) {
    $payload[$value['sname']] = '';
  }

  $payload[$value['sname']] .= (strlen($payload[$value['sname']]) >0?',':'') . $value['cname'];
}

print_r($payload);
```

Cheers! :)

=C=